When I run the code, the car instance of Car spawns at a y-coord below the player and off the screen size. How do i fix this bug?
I'm making a crossy game from 100 Days of code, except I'm making it from scratch since I don't have the recommended IDE(Pycharm) I used randrange to get an integer instead of randint because I'm using negative integers to generate a random y value.
Here is main.py:
from turtle import Screen 
from time import sleep
from player import Player
from car import Car

s = Screen()
s.setup(600, 600)
s.bgcolor('black')
s.tracer(0)

player = Player()
car = Car()

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    s.update()
    sleep(0.1)
    car.move()

player.py:
from turtle import Turtle as t

finish = 580
start = -580

class Player(t):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('square')
        self.penup()
        self.color('white')
        self.goto(0, -280)

    
    def left(self):
        self.forward(20)

    def right(self):
        self.backward(20)
    
    def up(self):
        self.setheading(90)
        self.forward(20)
        self.setheading(0)

and car.py:
from turtle import Turtle as t
from random import randrange

class Car(t):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('square')
        self.color('white')
        yval = randrange(-570, 570)
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len= 2)
        self.setx(560)
        self.sety(yval)
    
    def move(self):
        self.forward(-20)

I tried reversing the values of the integers in the randrange function from positive to negative to vice versa. I have doublechecked the values and the turtle coordinate system. Still does not work. When I run the program, the car does not appear and I go for fullscreen, which lets me see that the car is going BELOW the player.

The main problem here is simply that your range of y-values extends beyond the canvas.
On my machine*, the player shows up at the very bottom of the screen (specifically, y is -280), so setting the car to somewhere between -570 and +570 doesn't make sense. Either make the screen larger or choose sensible values. If the visible range is -280 to +280, make it that:
yval = randrange(-280, 280)

Keep in mind that you'll need to wait a second or two for the turtle's x-value to reach the visible canvas.
The turtle API provides screensize() and window_width() to avoid having to hardcode 280.
In general, a little experimentation is the best way to debug this. Start with placing the turtles smack dab in the middle of the canvas, so you can be sure you're rendering them properly, then gradually extend the range using hardcoded (non-random values).
Sometimes turtles are set to move so fast they shoot off the screen instantly--not the case here, but noting that setting speeds to 0 is another potential debugging approach to the common "dude, where's my turtle?" problem.
Beyond that, the design contains some potential pitfalls I suggest fixing sooner rather than later, but I'll defer to other threads for that:

Avoid while True: in real-time turtle applications

If you do need to sleep, do it at the end of your update loop: move positions, call .update(), then sleep() at the very last step.


Prefer composition, not inheritance, in turtle

* Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3.10.12
